# apache mod_rewrite currency

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, escaping

I was wondering if anyone can help. I have a redirect file set to point the customers to specific pages when they search on the site for specific words. This is all working fine with similar below rules apart from when i try to pass a GBP currency sign (£) in to the search string, so for instance if I wanted to send the customer to a page called 'http://www.mysite.com/offers/3-for-20.list' when they search for '3 for £20' i have got the below rule set up :-

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search\=(3\+for\+£20)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* http://www.mysite.com/offers/3-for-20.list?s=%1 [L,R=301]
```

I have tried the above without success and have been unable to find anything to help or any escape characters that will help me with this.
I am not getting any errors pages appear infact it is completing the search successfully but not pointing to the page requested insteadjust doing a query as if there is no redirect set up, plus the log files shows no errors but has a search result of '...search=3+for+%C2%A320' HTTP/1.1 200

I have also tried to put the above in to the redirect rule with the same results i.e.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search\=(3\+for\+C2%A320)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* http://www.mysite.com/offers/3-for-20.list?s=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the URI, the query string is treated a bit different as far as URL escaping goes. The URI is unescaped before being put through the rules, but the query string variable is left unescaped, Thus:

```
 search=3 for £20
```

is left unescaped in the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
search=3+for+%C2%A320
```

Additionally, when you backrefernce the match in your rewrite rule, mod_rewrite wants to escape the query string **again**, so you need to tell it not to using the `NE` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(3\+for\+%C2%A320)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* http://www.mysite.com/offers/3-for-20.list?s=%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

(your second attempt was missing a `%` before the `C2`)

Comment: oops missed that! That has done the trick thanks for your help :)